# Read parameters from a file which is not yet created with snakemake

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

I have a rule A which calculates some parameters and saves these to a file `PARAMS.txt`. Later, the rule B uses a python function to read the contents of `PARAMS.txt`.
The problem is that I get the following error:

```sh
InputFunctionException in line 21 of x.smk:
Error:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PARAMS.txt'
```

I guess the problem is, that that `PARAMS.txt` does not exist yet, which causes the function which reads its contents to fail.
This is a roughly how the Snakefile looks like:

```sh
def get_hla_types(wildcards):
    '''
    Read the input of the file
    '''
    # this file gets created by an upstream rule
    with open(f"{path}{wildcards.patient}/{wildcards.timepoint}/hla_types.txt", "r") as f:
        hla_types = f.read()
    return hla_types


rule antigen_garnish:
    input:
         ...

    output:
          ...


    params:
          hla_types=get_hla_types, # this causes the problem i think
          ...

    shell:
         "..." # cleanup container
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?
If somehow Snakemake would evaluate the rule `antigen.garnish` just if it was actually excecuted, everything should work fine. So my question is if this is possible.

It would also work if I could pass arguments to the input function. Then I could move it from the `params` section to the `input` section

Cheers!

Comment: You do have 'PARAMS.txt' listed as an input (dependency), don't you? It's hard to guess from your code.

Comment: No, I do not. I only indirectly reference it via the function which is listed in the `params` keyword

Comment: So you should have 'PARAMS.txt' as a dependency.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: In order for your question to be answerable, you should make sure your sample Snakefile matches your description. You talk about `PARAMS.txt` but that's nowhere to be found in your Snakefile. Your Snakefile mentions `{path}` but that variable isn't defined in your `Snakefile`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have not (yet) understood how Snakemake handles dependencies of rules. Your question is confusing because the Snakefile you provided doesn't have any file called `PARAMS.txt` and the variable `path` which is used by `get_hla_types` is not defined in your Snakefile. So this can't run for a number of reasons.

Here's the general architecture I'd use. I assume `path = PARAMS.txt`.

```py
path = 'PARAMS.txt'

rule A:
    output: 'PARAMS.txt'
    shell: 'touch PARAMS.txt' # or whatever command creates PARAMS.txt


def get_hla_types(wildcards):
    # this file gets created by an upstream rule
    with open(f"{path}{wildcards.patient}/{wildcards.timepoint}/hla_types.txt", "r") as f:
        hla_types = f.read()
    return hla_types

rule B:
    input: 'PARAMS.txt'
    output: 'output/{patient}/{timepoint}/result.txt'
    params:
        hla_types=get_hla_types,
    ...
```

Now before `rule B` is called, `rule B` is executed, because it requires `PARAMS.txt` which is produced by `rule A`.